# Laravel Soap vies Service_Unavailable and MS_MAX_CONCURRENT_REQ

Tags: laravel, soap

I want to confirm the vat number by using https://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/checkVatTestService.wsdl to the web service given on the Vies European Commission page, but I get the SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE error and ms_max_concurrent_req error, how can I reach the solution.

```
 $url="http://ec.europa.eu/taxation_customs/vies/checkVatService.wsdl";

    $result = $client = new SoapClient($url);
      $client->checkVat(array(
            'countryCode' => $request->memberStateCode,
            'vatNumber' => $request->number
        ));

    if($result->valid == true) {
        return "VAT code #".$request->memberStateCode.$request->number." is invalid.";
    } else {
        return "VAT code #".$request->memberStateCode.$request->number." is valid.";
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the mean of error MS_MAX_CONCURRENT_REQ: Your Request for VAT validation has not been processed; the maximum number of concurrent requests for this Member State has been reached.

Probaby u need to wait a while like 12-24 hours. After then you can try again. Let me know if you do that.

Comment: How can we know what is the max limit for a given member state @vedat-kurtay ?